# how to load a module in a component in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, module, components

I had use a code in joomla 1.5 to laod mod_related_items in com_content >> article:

```
<?php
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('module_type(example:"mod_related_items")','Position-name');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
?>

<?php echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayContent; ?>
```

I had use this code end of this file: `components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php`

now i want use this code in joomla 2.5.

when i used it in jooma 2.5, I had these errors:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\kknews.ir\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php
>   on line 152
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\kknews.ir\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php
>   on line 156
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\kknews.ir\libraries\joomla\application\module\helper.php
>   on line 159
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$content in
>   C:\wamp\www\kknews.ir\templates\system\html\modules.php on line 16

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
         $document = JFactory::getDocument();
         $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

         $Module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');

         $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";//If any params
         $Module->params = $Params;//If any params
         echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

Hope it works..

Comment: where i must put my position name? for example: position_one

Comment: pass the module name instead of position name like 'mod_fmDataGrid'